# Nav flickers when page is refreshed?

Tags: jquery, css, slide, nav

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Sazd/

When the page is refreshed the `ul` that is hidden flickers before hiding. How can I stop this from happening?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li ul').slideUp();

    $('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
        $('ul ul').slideUp(400);
        if($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
        else
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('li ul').slideUp();` that's your problem.. You're sliding it up on load. You could just set it to `display:none` initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a zero:

```
$('li ul').slideUp(0);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3Sazd/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: none` to initially hide the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Sazd/1/

EDIT: As others are suggesting, you can also hide the elements initially with JavaScript.  If you need the elements to be visible if JavaScript is disabled, that may be a better idea.  However, depending upon how long your page takes to load, they may still flicker for a bit.

Comment: I was just to post a fiddle doing the same thing. +1

Comment: Yep - although as mentioned if you use `hide()`, you may still get a flicker before the `jQuery` runs, (if you refresh the page multiple times in quick succession.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your `DOMReady` function to `hide()` instead of `slideUp()`:

```
$('li ul').hide();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Sazd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('li ul').slideUp();
```

to

```
$('li ul').hide();
```

That stops the initial slide up flicker that you are seeing

Comment: @explosion-pills `display: none` isn't ideal for screen readers where you don't want the elements hidden.